# Manage Cognito User Pool using JWT

Tags: amazon-cognito, serverless-framework, serverless

I have a Node.js lambda API that's called by an authenticated user. The user is able to access the API passing a valid JWT token. Now I'd like to interact with Cognito User Pool to change the user's email, password and etc but I haven't figured out how to achieve this using just the JWT.

I've made several tests using amplify-js and amazon-cognito-identity-js

Answer (score 0):

You can reset the user's password by calling an admin API call, not through the JWT token. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminResetUserPassword.html This will prompt the user for a new password.

This API call is to set a password for that particular user https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminSetUserPassword.html but I prefer the first option.

In order to change user attributes (such as email, birthday...), use https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminUpdateUserAttributes.html

So all these are done using the Cognito Service inside the Lambda (not to be confused with the JWT tokens).

Comment: I was not aware that there's an admin API. I looked at the documentation but I couldn't find to which endpoint should I send my requests and what config is necessary; Could point me in the right direction? Much appreciated.